# Pass interface type argument with one additional paramters in node js

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am currently working in node and I am facing an issue in function arguments, below is my code

```
const IPayload: PollOpinionIPayload = {
                    'questionText':questionText,
                    'opinionPollType':opinionPollType,
                    'duration':duration,
                    'templateId':templateId,
                    'maxSpentEnergy':maxSpentEnergy,
                    showId: 'test_one'

                }


const data = await ActivateOpinionPollCommand.execute({
                    questionText,
                    maxSpentEnergy,
                    opinionPollType,
                    duration,
                    templateId,
                    showId: 'test_one'

});
```

So in `ActivateOpinionPollCommand.execute` function, all arguments except `showId` covers in interface, so can anyone suggest me how can I pass that with interface?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wX7YOW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: const data = await ActivateOpinionPollCommand.execute({
                   IPayload,
                    showId: 'test_one'

});  I need to pass this way so can anyone would be suggest me?

Comment: Sorry, but that isn't a [mre].  If I put your example code into an IDE [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mqEdQm), I get a lot of errors. Are you asking about all of those errors?  If not, then you should [edit] the example code so that the only errors present are related to your question.  Please review the guidelines for [ask] and what makes code a [mre].